# The model backing the context has changed since the database was created

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a MVC5 WebApp and a Console App. The console app uses the same DbContext as of the WebApp.
(i.e I have DbContext named **WheelTrackDb** defined in WebApp and used in Console.)

I have added a reference to the web App and then in App.Config of Console App Specified the Connection String.

Now when I run the WebApp, It works well.

But when I run the console app it throws the below exception:

> The model backing the 'WheelTrackDb' context has changed since the
>   database was created. Consider using Code First Migrations to update
>   the database.

Any help to get the console app working shall be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are the connection string in the different projects points to the same database ?

Comment: Yes. I copied & Verified. Its exactly same.

Comment: Sorery if it's an obvious question but have you enabled code first migrations?

Comment: Yes, migrations are enabled. And the WebApp project runs.

Answer (score 0):

Add-Migration -Name

update-database